# C++ Classes a function-definition is not allowed here before "}"

Tags: c++, class

I've been trying to make a FFT with wxwidgets on linux, but I am not very familiar with C++.
I've tried two approaches both without any lucky, and I've been reading all about the errors looking for similar problems and I still don't understand what's wrong.

**First Approach (everything inside the class)**

```
#include <valarray>
#include <complex>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

class do_fft
{
public:
    typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
    typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;
        do_fft();
        virtual ~do_fft();
private:
    const static double PI = 3.141592653589793238460;
    CArray x;
    void setDados(CArray v)
    {
        CArray x = v;
    }
    CArray getFFT()
    {

        void fft(CArray& x)
        {  //line 27
            const size_t N = x.size();
            if (N <= 1) return;

            // divide
            CArray par = x[std::slice(0, N/2, 2)];
            CArray  impar = x[std::slice(1, N/2, 2)];

            // conquistar
            fft(par);
            fft(impar);

            // combinar
            for (size_t k = 0; k < N/2; ++k)
            {
                Complex t = std::polar(1.0, -2 * PI * k / N) * impar[k];
                x[k    ] = par[k] + t;
                x[k+N/2] = par[k] - t;
            }
        }
        fft(x);
        return x;
    } //line 49
} fftd;
```

**Errors when trying to compile:**

```
do_fft.h|49|error: expected ‘;’ after
class definition| do_fft.h||In member function ‘do_fft::CArray
do_fft::getFFT()’:| do_fft.h|27|error: a function-definition is not
allowed here before ‘{’ token| do_fft.h|49|error: expected ‘}’ at end
of input| do_fft.h|49|warning: no return statement in function
returning non-void
```

**Second Approach**  - Separate declarations from methods:

```
class do_fft
{
public:
    typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
    typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;
    //    do_fft();
    //    virtual ~do_fft();
private:
    const static double PI = 3.141592653589793238460;
    CArray x;
    void setDados(CArray v);
    CArray getFFT();
} fftd;


do_fft.cpp|3|error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘setDados’ with no type [-fpermissive]| 
do_fft.cpp|3|error: prototype for ‘int do_fft::setDados(do_fft::CArray)’ does not match any in class ‘do_fft’| 
do_fft.h|19|error: candidate is: void do_fft::setDados(do_fft::CArray)| do_fft.cpp|8|error: ‘getFFT’ in ‘class do_fft’ does not name a type| ||=== Build finished: 4 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

**My question is: what are the *concepts* that I am messing around and what would be the *proper way* to handle this ?**

EDIT: Other question-> what does **"virtual ~do_fft();"** this line? (the IDE inserted it when creating the class)

Comment: What is `fftd` after the `}` supposed to be?  `void fft` inside the `getFFT()` method is not legal C++ `setDados()` does nothing because it's setting local variable x instead of the class member.

Comment: I saw something similar in a tutorial. It was latter used as a shorter name for the class. (http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/). It's done after the CRectangle class (in the link).

Comment: nice - perhaps I should jump out of c# and go back to C++ for a refresher!

Comment: Just a quick note: If you `#include <cmath>` then there's the macro constant `M_PI`

Comment: `~do_fft()` is the so-called destructor of the class. That function should take care of cleaning up all of its resources and state. You can define it yourself. For now, you shouldn't worry about the `virtual` keyword in front of class functions, but it has to do with polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested function are not allowed in standard C++, you could do this:

```
class do_fft
{
public:
    typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
    typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;
        do_fft();
        virtual ~do_fft();
private:
    const static double PI = 3.141592653589793238460;
    CArray x;
    void setDados(CArray v)
    {
        CArray x = v;
    }

    void fft(CArray& x)
    {  //line 27
       const size_t N = x.size();
       if (N <= 1) return;

       // divide
       CArray par = x[std::slice(0, N/2, 2)];
       CArray  impar = x[std::slice(1, N/2, 2)];

       // conquistar
       fft(par);
       fft(impar);

       // combinar
       for (size_t k = 0; k < N/2; ++k)
       {
           Complex t = std::polar(1.0, -2 * PI * k / N) * impar[k];
           x[k    ] = par[k] + t;
           x[k+N/2] = par[k] - t;
       }
    }


    CArray getFFT()
    {
        fft(x);
        return x;
    } //line 49
} fftd;
```

Also, the line

```
virtual ~do_fft();
```

Is the declaration of the destructor of this class, a function used for release all what you need when an instance of this class is deleted.

Comment: Nesting a function inside another function *directly* is not allowed in C++, but you can nest a type and define a `static` member function as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have invalid code after `void fft`
2. `setDados` has `void` return type in the class definition, but it returns `int` in your cpp file which you don't provide.
3. `virtual ~do_fft()` is a virtual destructor. If you will derive from this class, it is recommended. If not, it's unnecessary.

Comment: setdados was suposed to be just "void setDados(CArray v) { CArray x = v; }" .It was how I expected to set vector X, that would be used later.